# what's the entry point of kaa editor? (freezing kaa on linux)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.3

i want to "Freeze" (i.e. create self executable, self contained package) Kaa Editor.

(reason: It runs only on python3.3+, but my production servers have python2.7 and python3.2, and i don't want to change it)

What's the main script that runs kaa?
I feel a bit stupid, after 13 years of python development, but I can't find it.

here's /usr/local/bin/kaa

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'kaaedit==0.11.0','console_scripts','kaa'
__requires__ = 'kaaedit==0.11.0'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('kaaedit==0.11.0', 'console_scripts', 'kaa')()
    )
```

this is probably a trivial python question - but **what's the python script command line to run kaa?**

in i tried so far to freeze kaa with:

1. PyInstaller isn't yet supported on python3.
2. python's built in "freeze" - i can't make it to work due to strange errors.
3. cx_freeze - accepts /usr/local/bin/kaa but complains, and the output doesn't run.

Here's the output:

```
 $ cx_freeze /usr/local/bin/kaa
 ...
 Missing modules:
 ? _sysconfigdata_d imported from _sysconfigdata
 ? importlib._bootstrap imported from pkg_resources

 $ ./kaa

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 696, in require
     needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 594, in resolve
     raise DistributionNotFound(req)
```

basically i just want the kaa frozen, but i'm asking for help on the above question as well.

Comment: similar question (unanswered) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774778/python-understanding-easy-install-entry-points

Answer (score 0):

I freeze kaa for Mac OS X and same script worked for Ubuntu 13.10. I hope it works for older ubuntu too.

1. Install libs for Python

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get build-dep python3.2
   ```
2. Untar Python 3.3 source distribution and apply following two patch.

   http://bugs.python.org/issue11824

   http://bugs.python.org/issue16047
3. ./configure, make and make install dance.
4. Clone source tree of kaa.

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/kaaedit/kaa.git
   ```
5. In source directory of kaa, cd to kaa/freezing directory.
6. Edit PYTHON variable in build.sh for your environment.
7. run build.sh
8. Check freezing/dist/kaa exists.

Comment: A) In step #1 you wrote python3.2, typo?  B) Can you please paste here the build.sh file you had for your mac-build?

Comment: thank you, but i gave up on kaa for now, due to inability to use my python3 properly.  i'll wait till python3.3 is stable before I go on with it.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear that build.sh is in source tree of kaa. https://github.com/kaaedit/kaa/blob/master/freezing/build.sh

See you.

Comment: the files mentioned in "build.sh" are missing from kaaedit-13.   i'll try to pull the git repo.